# Can GEB be used to run the same test for each set of data in a collection?

Tags: automated-tests, spock, geb

I would like to save all my user data into an collection and have GEB run the same test for each set of data.  I am thinking something like this.

```
import geb.spock.GebReportingSpec
import spock.lang.*

class MyFirstTestSpec extends GebReportingSpec {

    def setupSpec() {
       def userData = //an array of hashes but if it work I really do not care what type of collection is used 
    }

    def 'run app'() {
    given:
            to LoginPage
            userName = 'MasterUser'
            password = 'APassword'
            login.click()
            at HomePage
    when:
    userData.each{
            to ProfilePage
            first = it['first']
            mi = it['mi']
            last = it['last']

            ...... More data
        }

    then: 'did it work'
        at ReviewPage
        amount1     == it['amount1']
        amount2     == it['amount12']

            ...... More checks 


}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered moving the userData to a **where:** block?

```
import geb.spock.GebReportingSpec
import spock.lang.*

class MyFirstTestSpec extends GebReportingSpec {

def setupSpec() {
}

def 'run app'() {
    given:
        to LoginPage
        userName = 'MasterUser'
        password = 'APassword'
        login.click()
        at HomePage
    when:
        to ProfilePage
        first = firstName
        mi = midName
        last = lastName

        ...... More data
    then: 'did it work'
        at ReviewPage

        reviewFirstName == firstName

        amount1     == amount1
        amount2     == amount12

        ...... More checks 
    where:
        firstName | midName | lastName | amount1 | amount12
        Robert    | John    | Brown    | 100     | 20
...more data
```

The only thing with this structure is that the login process would need to fire for each iteration.  If that's not to your liking then you could use a **where:** block and move the **given:** block out to a **setupSpec()** fixture method.

Comment: You can run closure's in the where block and return the lists you need for each variable doing this - you can then navigate anywhere and do any pre processing required before the tests start.